# World coordinates in 2D model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to position the viewer-camera based on world/model coordinates over a 2D CAD file. How can world coordinates be calculated for 2D models in APS viewer? viewer.modelGetData().globalOffset seems to be undefined, and modelGetData().modelSpaceBBox seems to be set to a rectangle of 11 times 8.5 units, which corresponds to a Letter size paper. So the model seems to be "plotted" into a sheet by the derivative api.

Comment: can you please specify the input file you're using? Is this a 2D from a DWG or a 2D view from a Revit file?

Comment: Hello, I found the solution in this article: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/parsing-line-points-viewer. It shows how to transform viewer coordinates back into CAD source file coordinates using .model.getPageToModelTransform()